# Populate model with data from another model

Tags: django, django-admin

I have the following models about a person and I've made a button, in the admin interface -in Person-, to go to a class Contract where I add a contract to the related person:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name=_(u"Name"))
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name=_(u"Surname"))
    address = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name=_(u"Address"))

class Contract(models.Model):
    person        = models.ForeignKey(Person) #person hired
    project       = models.ForeignKey(Project, blank = True, null = True) #related project
    starting_date = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True)
    ending_date   = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True)
```

**myproject/templates/admin/myapp/Person/change_form.html**

```
    {% block after_field_sets %}
    <input type="button" value="New contract" onClick=" window.location.href='../../contract/add/' ">
    {% endblock %}
```

Is there any way to populate automatically the field person, in the class Contract, with the person it comes from?

Moreover, if I go to Contract directly from the admin panel should have the default behaviour (not filled).

Comment: I think, from memory, you can just append `?person_id=<id>` to the contract editing url

Comment: @Anentropic I've tried it but nothing happens. As far as I've seen there's no way to pass an object so that the url resolves the keywords from that object and I can't find any documentation or a third party app.

Comment: it works for me in Django 1.4, but it needs to be eg `?person=3` and not `person_id`.  It has to be an already existing person saved in the db of course though

Comment: @Anentropic so I couldn't do it automatically? I mean, do I need to specify the person?

Comment: yes you need to specify the actual person id in the querystring, so that it knows which person to pre-fill for the new Contract

Comment: @Anentropic it's ok, but as I have a few hundreds persons I need to do it somehow automatically

Comment: you can use a template var, no?

Comment: @Anentropic How could I go about it?

Comment: you already added a new button to the Person admin template, in that template you should have access to a var with the id of the Person you're currently editing

Comment: @Anentropic Where I could find an example?

Comment: please post the code you are already using to insert the new button and I may be able to provide a complete answer